# How to combine Python string and list with a \n in it

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I am trying to combine a string "name_of_students" and a list "science["name"]"

I did try this and it works but I am trying to make it more efficient by combining line 2 and line 3. Idea is to pick every element from list and append it to string but on a new line (/n).

```
name_of_students = "Student for science is as below:"
for science in input_stream:
        if input_name_prefix in science["name"]:
            if science["name"] not in [
                sciencestream["stream_name"] for sciencestream in sciencestream_limited_streams
            ]:
                name_of_students.append(science["name"])
                name_of_students = "\n".join(name_of_students)
```

My attempt: I did try but this fails when I iterate it through a for loop

```
name_of_students = "\n".join(name_of_students + [science["name"]])
```

Error with my attempt:

```
ERROR] TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

Is there a good way to do this?
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: is `science` a dictionary? and `science["name"]` a list?

Comment: `name_of_students` is a string, how exactly are you using `append` on it?

Comment: Why not `"\n".join([name_of_students] + science["name"])`?

Comment: what does science look like? It seems like science is a dictionary so that’s why I ask. Also append is a list method as is join. It seems like they’re trying to be being used as string methods right now.

Comment: will be good to print out `science['name']` and `science`

Comment: @Jordan @Gold79 @Guy @najeem
```science``` is a dict and ```name``` is the key of the dictionary and ```science["name"]``` is just a string value of that dictionary.

Comment: @Timus thats because on the second iteration it gives an error saying ```ERROR] TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str```

Comment: Your question is very unclear: What _iterations_? In the question you said _"a list "science["name"]"_, and in the comment you say _"science["name"] is just a string value"_?

Comment: Please provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that includes your expected output. And take look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: let me edit the question here to clear the confusion, Sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Assumptions:

Okay, so this is what I understand -

`sciencestream_limited_streams` looks something like this:

```py
sciencestream_limited_streams = [{"stream_name": "tomlastname", "other_key": "other_val"},{"stream_name": "johndoe", "other_key":"other_val"},{"stream_name":"janedoe", "other_key": "other_val"},{"stream_name": "alt_streamer", "other_key":"other_val"}]
```

`input_stream` looks something like this:

```py
input_stream = [{"name": "Mr.sciencename_val", "other_key": "other_val", "another_key": "another_val"},{"name": "second_val", "other_key": "other_val1", "another_key": "another_val2"},{"name": "third_val", "other_key": "other_val", "another_key": "another_val"},{"name": "fourth_val", "other_key": "other_val1", "another_key": "another_val2"}]
```

`input_name_prefix` is a `str` val, since this is an example, the mock `str` will look like this:

```py
input_name_prefix = "Mr."
```

***Note:*** *Notice how `Mr.sciencename_val` **is in** `input_stream` but **not in** `sciencestream_limited_streams`*.

---

##### Solution:

If the above assumptions are correct in structure, you could try something like this:

```py
# Add newline character to name_of_students
name_of_students = "Student for science is as below:\n"

# List of stream_name values
stream_names = [sciencestream["stream_name"] for sciencestream in sciencestream_limited_streams]

for science in input_stream:
    # initialize a variable for science["name"]
    name = science["name"]
    if input_name_prefix in name:
        if name not in stream_names:
            name_of_students += name
```

***Note:*** *I kept your code as close to the original as I could, I just cleaned it up a bit.*

---

##### Output:

Then if you were to `print(name_of_students)` after using the above code and mock data, the output would be:

```
Student for science is as below:
Mr.sciencename_val
```